# Animation like minimizing and maximizing screens on Mac OS X

Tags: iphone, animation

I am developing an iPhone application where

1. I need to provide an animation which is used by Mac OS X while minimizing and maximizing the screen to an UIImageView.
2. Need the animation on an image which continously give pulse effect (i.e. continous zoomin/out)(PS: I have done this using two images but I want to know whether its possible with single image).
3. Image must come in full size from the screen with alpha as 0 and then go to the center of the screen increasing alpha at each move till it reaches its orignal position.

Any help would be really appreciated..

Thanks

Comment: Mac = [Macintosh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macintosh), MAC = [MAC address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address)

Comment: [Typography-loving Steve Jobs](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UF8uR6Z6KLc) would hate you if he saw it written in all-caps

Comment: Oooppppss... thanks again for dat too....   Mac=Macintosh   :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not predefined, but checkout these [WWDC2010 Videos](https://developer.apple.com/videos/archive/) for informations on how to do it:

- Session 424 - Core Animation in Practice, Part 1
- Session 425 - Core Animation in Practice, Part 2

Answer (score 0):

This animation is quite complex. I think it is done my manipulating the CGAffinityTransform of the window. It can be implemented the old-school way with a timer and updating the transformation matrix manually or you could maybe even use CoreAnimation. I think there is an animatable value function for this.

Comment: also i want an animation with the pulse effect (i.e. zoom in /out continously). Is there any way to do it?

Comment: That is kind of easy. There is a scale property you can use. To make it pulse forever, just enable autoreverse and set repeat count to infinity. However to get a better understanding, I would suggest looking into the WWDC10 sessions vikingosegundo proposed.